# Using multiple websockets in a form with different url

Tags: javascript, html, web, websocket

I am using multiple WebSocket in a form with different URL In onkeydown event of each input, one web socket with one URL is created and closed. On alt+down key pressing in each input, a new WebSocket will create with another URL. Here WebSocket is used to get client response when executing backend function, Ajax cannot be used here because we cannot generate any client-side response message(like any confirm box) while back end code execution is going on. In our code, I need to take response from the client side and continue with the server side code without any break.

```
function()
***********
code block1()
alert("You want to continue?");   //get response from user
if yes                            //
code block2()                     //resume backend execution
else
code block3()
endif
return
```

Comment: Is that JavaScript?

Comment: No, This is a backend function. Can I use multiple WebSockets in same form ie.opening and closing each time. Is there any other method to implement this functionality?